# List of resources for spring batch job execution

Tags: spring-batch

I have requirement to process a flatfile through spring batch job execution. I get the list of files from the folder which needs to be processed. Please let me know how to accomplish this.

For example: 
I have `player.csv` and `player1.csv` and `player2.csv` in a folder. I have these file names in a list. Please let me know if I can input all these files names for Jobparameters so that I can execute a single Job ?

```
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("input.file", "file:player.csv").toJobParameters();
JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job,jobParameters);
assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, execution.getExitStatus());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a couple of ways you can do this;
1. create a job to process one file at a time and have your job initiator iterate over the files and trigger the job, passing in only one file at a time
2. create a 'loop' inside your job to go over the values and process each file

here's an example of the latter option;

first the job configuration - it uses a decider to build an execution context value for the file to process.  if there are no more files (from the jobParameter), then it finishes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">

    <batch:job id="multipleFileProcess">
        <batch:decision decider="decider" id="multipleFileProcess.decider">
            <batch:next on="UNKNOWN" to="multipleFileProcess.step1"/>
            <batch:end on="COMPLETED"/>
        </batch:decision>
        <batch:step id="multipleFileProcess.step1" next="multipleFileProcess.decider">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="fileReader" writer="outWriter" commit-interval="10"/>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:validator>
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.job.DefaultJobParametersValidator">
                <property name="requiredKeys" value="input.files"/>
            </bean>         
        </batch:validator>
    </batch:job>


    <bean id="fileReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="lineMapper" ref="lineMapper"/>
        <property name="resource" value="file:#{jobExecutionContext['input.file']}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="lineMapper"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughLineMapper"/>


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager">
    </bean>

    <bean id="decider" class="de.incompleteco.spring.batch.decider.FileDecision"/>

    <bean id="outWriter" class="de.incompleteco.spring.batch.item.writer.SystemOutItemWriter"/>

</beans>
```

here's the decider code (using an internal queue - it would probably be safer to maintain this 'queue' as an string in the execution context that you slowly shorten (manually 'pop' an entry of the string - but for quickness used a queue)

```
package de.incompleteco.spring.batch.decider;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobExecutionDecider;

public class FileDecision implements JobExecutionDecider {

    public static final String INPUT_FILE = "input.file";
    public static final String INPUT_FILES = "input.files";
    public static final String DELIMITER = ",";

    private Queue<String> inputFiles;

    @Override
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution,StepExecution stepExecution) {
        //check if the jobExecution has the input.file in it's context
        if (!jobExecution.getExecutionContext().containsKey(INPUT_FILE)) {
            //build the queue
            inputFiles = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(Arrays.asList(jobExecution.getJobParameters().getString(INPUT_FILES).split(DELIMITER)));
        }//end if
        //pop and add
        String file = inputFiles.poll();
        if (file != null) {
            jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put(INPUT_FILE, file);
            return FlowExecutionStatus.UNKNOWN;
        }//end if
        //return 'done'
        return FlowExecutionStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

}
```

here's the dummy 'writer' to show the file as its 'written' out

```
package de.incompleteco.spring.batch.item.writer;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;

public class SystemOutItemWriter implements ItemWriter<String> {

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
        for (String item : items) {
            System.out.println("this is what was received:" + item);
        }//end for
    }

}
```

and lastly the unit test to see if this runs

```
package de.incompleteco.spring.batch;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import de.incompleteco.spring.batch.decider.FileDecision;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/META-INF/spring/*-context.xml")
public class MultipleFileProcessIntegrationTest {

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Resource
    private Job job;

    @Resource
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Resource
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        //somewhere to hold the filenames
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        //create 3 files
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            File file = folder.newFile("testfile" + i + ".txt");
            //write some content
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write("test content: " + i);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            //add the filename
            if (i > 0) {
                builder.append(FileDecision.DELIMITER);
            }//end if
            builder.append(file.getAbsolutePath());
            //show it
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }//end loop


        //now build the job parameters
        JobParameters parameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString(FileDecision.INPUT_FILES,builder.toString()).toJobParameters();
        //execution
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job,parameters);
        //check
        while (jobExplorer.getJobExecution(execution.getId()).isRunning()) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }//end while
        //load
        execution = jobExplorer.getJobExecution(execution.getId());
        //check
        assertFalse(execution.getStatus().isUnsuccessful());
    }

}
```